# Promise all and correctly update the state using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, fetch-api

Fetching data from API I'm getting such data:

```
0: {name: "bulbasaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/1/"}
1: {name: "ivysaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon- species/2/"}
2: {name: "venusaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/3/"}
3: {name: "charmander", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/4/"}
4: {name: "charmeleon", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/5/"}
5: {name: "charizard", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/6/"}
```

In order to get more detailed information I need to fetch each url. I'm trying to do it with Promise.all and update state, but code doesn't work:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemons: [],
      names: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadPokemons();
    this.loadPokemonAdditionalInfo();
  }
  loadPokemons() {
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          names: json.results
        })
      })
  }
  loadPokemonAdditionalInfo() {
    Promise.all(this.state.names.map(name =>
      fetch(name.url)
      .then(results => results.forEach(result => result.json())
        .then(r => {
          this.setState({
            pokemons: [...this.state.pokemons, r]
          })
        }))))
  }
}
```

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when you attempt to load the additional data, the names won't have finished.

Just make your `componentDidMount` function async and await each call (also make sure you're returning a promise for each one).

```
async componentDidMount(){
  await this.loadPokemons();
  await this.loadPokemonAdditionalInfo();
}
```

Also you are returning the iteration of the results, not an array of each result's json.

Replace `results.forEach(result => result.json())` with:

`results.map(result => result.json())` in `loadPokemonAdditionalInfo`

---

```js
const results = [{ name:'John' }, { name:'Jane' }];

console.log('forEach', results.forEach(result => result.name));
console.log('map', results.map(result => result.name));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this operation with async-await doesn't help. Is there any other way how to do it? Also, why use map instead of forEach?

Comment: The `forEach` function is only iterating the array and doesn't return anything. You need the map function to actually map the results to a new array of names.

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all should have array or promises , so the argument should be array of fetches .

```js
Promise.all(this.state.names.map(name =>
  fetch(name.url)))
  .then(results => results.forEach(result => result.json())
  .then(r => {
    this.setState({
      pokemons: [...this.state.pokemons, r]
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're calling both loadPokemons and loadPokemonAdditionalInfo as soon your component mounts. You need to wait until you have fetched the pokemons name, before you fetch their additional info.

`this.loadPokemonAdditionalInfo()` should be called from setState callback like

```
this.setState({
   isLoaded: true,
    names: json.results
}, this.loadPokemonAdditionalInfo)
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi and Stephan! You are right and helped me a lot! It works now!

Answer (score 1):

You can't run both

```
this.loadPokemons();
this.loadPokemonAdditionalInfo();
```

in synchronous way, setState takes some time to change state. That's why there is a callback to setState.

Following should work:

```
loadPokemons(){
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        names: json.results
      }, () => {
        this.loadPokemonAdditionalInfo()
      })
    })
}

loadPokemonAdditionalInfo() {
  const { names } = this.state;
  const promises = names.map(
    name => fetch(name.url).then(response => response.json())
  )
  Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    this.setState({
      pokemons: [...this.state.pokemons, ...results]
    })
  })
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.loadPokemons();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works now! Wow! Thank you so much for an explanation and your help!